Is there any way to fill the area where multiple lines intersect with black?
 \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw(0,0) rectangle (12,8);
 \foreach \x in {3.5,3.8,...,5.6}{
 \draw (\x,0)--(4.4,8);
 }
 \foreach \x in {7.5,7.8,...,9.6}{
 \draw (\x,0)--(8.4,8);
 }
 
  \foreach \y in {1,1.3,...,3.1}{
 \draw (12,\y)--(0,1.9);
 }
 
  \foreach \y in {4,4.3,...,6.1}{
 \draw (12,\y)--(0,4.9);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




You can do this with the help of the intersections library (change to black as needed, I just used red to make it more visible):
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) rectangle (12,8);
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {3.5,3.8,...,5.6}{
    \draw[name path global=xa\xi] (\x,0)--(4.4,8);
}

\foreach \x [count=\xii] in {7.5,7.8,...,9.6}{
    \draw[name path global=xb\xii] (\x,0)--(8.4,8);
}

\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {1,1.3,...,3.1}{
    \draw[name path global=ya\yi] (12,\y)--(0,1.9);
}

\foreach \y [count=\yii] in {4,4.3,...,6.1}{
    \draw[name path global=yb\yii] (12,\y)--(0,4.9);
}

\foreach \x in {1,7} {
    \foreach \y in {1,7} {
        \edef\tempaa{
            \noexpand\path[name intersections={of=xa\x\space and ya\y}] 
                coordinate (xa\x-ya\y) at (intersection-1);
        }\tempaa
        \edef\tempab{
            \noexpand\path[name intersections={of=xa\x\space and yb\y}] 
                coordinate (xa\x-yb\y) at (intersection-1);
        }\tempab
        \edef\tempba{
            \noexpand\path[name intersections={of=xb\x\space and ya\y}] 
                coordinate (xb\x-ya\y) at (intersection-1);
        }\tempba
        \edef\tempbb{
            \noexpand\path[name intersections={of=xb\x\space and yb\y}] 
                coordinate (xb\x-yb\y) at (intersection-1);
        }\tempbb
    }
}
\fill[red] (xa1-ya1) -- (xa1-ya7) -- (xa7-ya7) -- (xa7-ya1) -- cycle;
\fill[red] (xa1-yb1) -- (xa1-yb7) -- (xa7-yb7) -- (xa7-yb1) -- cycle;
\fill[red] (xb1-ya1) -- (xb1-ya7) -- (xb7-ya7) -- (xb7-ya1) -- cycle;
\fill[red] (xb1-yb1) -- (xb1-yb7) -- (xb7-yb7) -- (xb7-yb1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



thank you very much
